# Why in the graph of compton effect , the width related with the second peak higher than that of the 1st peak?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Why in the graph of compton effect between the intensity vs. wavelength of scattered photons, the width related with the 2nd peak is quite larger than that of 1st peak for all values of angle ?

I provide the pictures , that will help to be clear about the question.
plese note the last two graphs
[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have the axes labeled so we know what these plots mean.

Comment: this is beteen intensity versus wavelength of scattered photons

Comment: Please put this in the question. Also, intensity of *what*?